# Express - Validation express-validator does not show errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, express-validator

I'm sure this is not a problem instead I'm not using it the right way.

I want to validate user request body and according to documentation, all work is done in the route file. And I divided my work into routes and controllers files. I passed a validation middleware and it needs to be validated but it's not. Something wrong in between.

My route is:

```
router.post(
  '/signup',
  userController.validateRequest,
  userController.hashPassword,
  userController.signup
);
```

Instead of this, if I did this way:

```
router.post(
  '/signup',
  body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Please enter a valid email'),
  body('password')
      .equals('confirmPassword')
      .withMessage('Passwords do not match'), 
  userController.hashPassword,
  userController.signup
);
```

**That will work** But this will makes code messy if several validation requests are there.

I just want to know what is the correct way, if I separate requests and validation middleware OR do I have to pass validation in route file **ONLY**. Please correct me if I'm doing it the wrong way.

My validation middleware is:

```
exports.validateRequest = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.email) {
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Please enter a valid email');
  }

  if (req.body.password_confirm) {
    body('password')
      .equals('confirmPassword')
      .withMessage('Passwords do not match');
  }
  next();
};
```

And my controller where all error messages are displaying

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  ............
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i prefer [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) the most powerful validator

```
async createAccountSchema(req, res, next) {
    // create schema object
    const schema = Joi.object({
      email: Joi.string().email().required(),

      password: Joi.string()
        .min(8)
        .required(),
      confirmPassword: Joi.string()
        .valid(Joi.ref('password'))
        .required()
        .label('Passwords')
        .messages({ 'any.only': '{{#label}} are not the same' }),
    })

    // schema options
    const options = {
      abortEarly: false, // include all errors
      allowUnknown: true, // ignore unknown props
      stripUnknown: true, // remove unknown props
    }

    // validate request body against schema

    const result = schema.validate(req.body, options)

    if (result.error) {
      return res.status(400).json(result.error.details)
    } else {
      result.value.email = result.value.email.trim().toLowerCase()
      result.value.password = result.value.password
      req.body = result.value
      next()
    }
  }
```

Thats an example for the validator. You pass `req.body` to the validator and it do the job.

After validating you set your `req.body` to the validation result and use `next()`

```
app.use("/", createAccountSchema, userController.signup)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me Joi @ifaruki. I explored Joi, but I have a confusion. Do I need to insert Joi and make entire mongoose schema according to Joi and then validate schema in controller OR Do I have to make all validation process in middleware like your example here?